# ImageProcessor.Web custom IImageService causes NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, imageprocessor

I've tried implementing a custom IImageService both in Umbraco and in a vanilla MVC app following the advice here:

https://github.com/JimBobSquarePants/ImageProcessor/issues/105

But I think I might be missing a step as I only get this error:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   ImageProcessor.Web.HttpModules.<ProcessImageAsync>d__b.MoveNext() +755
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   System.Web.TaskAsyncHelper.EndTask(IAsyncResult ar) +71
   System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +380
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

The DatabaseImageService below gets called on the Prefix property and IsFileLocalSevice but then I get the error above. IsValidRequest() and GetImage() never get called.

The code is a copy of [LocalFileImageService.cs](https://github.com/JimBobSquarePants/ImageProcessor/blob/master/src/ImageProcessor.Web/Services/LocalFileImageService.cs)

I have also tried specifying this ImageService in the security.config file that comes with ImageProcessor.Web.Config but the same error occurs.

```
namespace ImageProcessorTest
{
    public class DatabaseImageService : IImageService
    {
        private string prefix = "database.axd";

        public string Prefix
        {
            get
            {
                return this.prefix;
            }

            set
            {
                this.prefix = value;
            }
        }

        public bool IsFileLocalService
        {
            get
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        public Dictionary<string, string> Settings { get; set; }

        public Uri[] WhiteList { get; set; }

        public bool IsValidRequest(string path)
        {
            return ImageHelpers.IsValidImageExtension(path);
        }

        public async Task<byte[]> GetImage(object id)
        {
            string path = id.ToString();
            byte[] buffer;

            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(path);

            if (!fileInfo.Exists)
            {
                throw new HttpException((int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "No image exists at " + path);
            }

            using (FileStream file = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 4096, true))
            {
                buffer = new byte[file.Length];
                await file.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, (int)file.Length);
            }

            return buffer;
        }
    }
}
```

**Update 1**

The code example above is in a vanilla MVC App. The configuration is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<security>
  <services>
    <service name="LocalFileImageService" type="ImageProcessor.Web.Services.LocalFileImageService, ImageProcessor.Web" />
    <!--Disable the LocalFileImageService and enable this one when using virtual paths. -->
    <!--<service name="CloudImageService" type="ImageProcessor.Web.Services.CloudImageService, ImageProcessor.Web">
      <settings>
        <setting key="Container" value=""/>
        <setting key="MaxBytes" value="8194304"/>
        <setting key="Timeout" value="30000"/>
        <setting key="Host" value="http://yourhost.com/"/>
      </settings>
    </service>-->
    <service prefix="remote.axd" name="RemoteImageService" type="ImageProcessor.Web.Services.RemoteImageService, ImageProcessor.Web">
      <settings>
        <setting key="MaxBytes" value="4194304" />
        <setting key="Timeout" value="3000" />
        <setting key="Protocol" value="http" />
      </settings>
      <whitelist>
      </whitelist>
    </service>
    **<service prefix="database.axd" name="DatabaseImageService" type="ImageProcessorTest.DatabaseImageService, ImageProcessorTest" />**
  </services>
</security>
```

To be clear I have done the following steps to get to this point:

- Vanilla MVC App
- Installed: ImageProcessor ImageProcessor.Web and ImageProcessor.Web.Config via NuGet
- Created the DatabaseImageService class above
- Edited the security.config as shown

I have an image in the root of the site "hami-1.jpg". I can manipulate it correctly with the default LocalFileImageService http://localhost:11832/hami-1.jpg?width=200 .

The prefix I have specified for my custom IImageService is "database.axd" so the url should be either: ?

- http://localhost:11832/database.axd/hami-1.jpg?width=200
- http://localhost:11832/database.axd?hami-1.jpg?width=200

? I'm not sure at this point because I have seen examples of both. ?

In any case when I am debugging I do not hit any breakpoints in the IsValidRequest or GetImage methods. I do hit a breakpoint in IsFileLocalService.

It is a really basic setup so I'm sure it's something I'm missing.

Ultimately I want to replace the GetImage method with my own that will retrieve images from a database using something like:

```
private AppContext _db = new AppContext();

private MembershipService MembershipService
{
    get
    {
        if (ms == null)
        {
            ms = new MembershipService(_db, UmbracoContext.Current);
        }
        return ms;
    }
}

public async Task<byte[]> GetImage(object id = null)
{
    var image = await _db.Images.FindAsync(id);
    var currentMember = MembershipService.GetCurrentMember();
    if (image != null)
    {
        var content = image.Content;
        _db.Dispose();
        switch (image.Privacy)
        {
            case Models.Base.Privacy.Private:
                if (image.Owner.Id == currentMember.Id ||MembershipService.FindMembersInRole(currentMember.UmbracoMember.Username, "Judges").Any())
                    return content;
                break;
            case Models.Base.Privacy.Unlisted:
                return content;
            case Models.Base.Privacy.Public:
                return content;
        }
    }
    throw new HttpException(404, "Image not found for id: " + id);
}
```

Comment: Post the code where you are initializing and calling this class.

Comment: @CathalMF The Class is initialised and called from within ImageProcessor. See line 330 and 381 from [ImageProcessorConfiguration.cs](https://github.com/JimBobSquarePants/ImageProcessor/blob/master/src/ImageProcessor.Web/Configuration/ImageProcessorConfiguration.cs)

It is called in the method on line 722 in [ImageProcessingModule.cs](https://github.com/JimBobSquarePants/ImageProcessor/blob/master/src/ImageProcessor.Web/HttpModules/ImageProcessingModule.cs)

Comment: Is this the full code sample in it's current state? It appears to me you are still attempting to load a file from the local file system. Can you post both your configuration and an example url request?

Comment: @JamesSouth It is the code sample I'm currently testing with and still get the same issue. I go into it in more detail in my update. Thanks

Comment: @JosephTossell Not forgotten this, just not had time to test. Will have a look tonight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by you not initializing the `Settings` property in your service so when we check for the presence of a certain property

```
string protocol = currentService.Settings.ContainsKey("Protocol")
```

The exception is thrown.

Additionally you are incorrectly setting the `IsFileLocalService` property to true.

In the HttpModule there is a check against that property.

```
requestPath = currentService.IsFileLocalService
                            ? HostingEnvironment.MapPath(request.Path)
                            : request.Path;
```

This property means that the file is contained on the local file system. If you set it to true without the file being present in that way you will get an exception.

Comment: Thank you very much. Apologies for not marking this sooner as have been away. I have implemented and confirm it solves my issue too.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same issue using the latest NuGet Packages.  I have fixed this for now by downgrading the NuGet packages I am using to the following.

**ImageProcessor** - v2.2.5

**ImageProcessor.Web** - v4.3.2

**ImageProcess.Web.Config** - v1.0.0